# XML stream processing

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I've been looking through the page but I was not able to find any answer to my problem:

I'm downloading a XML file from a server through a stream and processing it using XmlReader:

```
XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create(XMLstream, settings);
while (xml.Read())
{
...
}
```

So the XML is being downloaded while it's being parsed, which is what I want for efficency reasons (I don't usually need to read the full document).

The problem is that sometimes, I'm facing a problem that already appeared in this website, which is that the XML contains non standard characters, which leads to exceptions.

I know how to filter this characters with XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(), and a  method to perform this clean up would be: download full XML code -> filter -> pass filtered string to XmlReader.
The problem with this method is that I have to download the full XML file, and sometimes this could be up to 10MB in slow connections!

Is there any method (callback or something) to filter the information just before the chunk of XML code is parsed?

As far as I know the method XmlReader.Read() manages the stream and the parse the result, but I need something in the middle.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show some of the XML thats causing problems?

Comment: @AlexK. the XML code contains some non-valid UTF-8 characters, which is the root of the problem (makes no sense to show you that because those are non-readable characters). I know how to remove the characters if I have the source string, but I don't know how to get that string. I mean that I don't know how to be in the middle (callback or similar) of the read() function

Comment: Obviously, you should read a stream of raw bytes, chunk by chunk, replace invalid data and pass to XmlReader.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderPetrov, I think that is the right direction, the problem is that I don't have any idea on how to do this. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!